# Cannot use ros::Time::now() before the first NodeHandle has been created or ros::start() has been called

Tags: ros, tf2, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Under Hydro  the following minimal example

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('sandbox')
import rospy
import tf

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node("test_tf_listener")
    listener = tf.TransformListener()
    (trans, rot) = listener.waitForTransform('test_1', 'test_2', rospy.Time(0), rospy.Duration(0))
```

result in this error:

```
$ rosrun sandbox test_tf_listener.py 
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'ros::TimeNotInitializedException'
  what():  Cannot use ros::Time::now() before the first NodeHandle has been created or ros::start() has been called.  If this is a standalone app or test that just uses ros::Time and does not communicate over ROS, you may also call ros::Time::init()
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Whats wrong?

### Update 1: backtrace

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff68e1425 in raise () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff68e4b8b in abort () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007ffff34c069d in __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#3  0x00007ffff34be846 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#4  0x00007ffff34be873 in std::terminate() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#5  0x00007ffff34be96e in __cxa_throw () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#6  0x00007ffff41777d4 in ros::Time::now() () from /opt/ros/hydro/lib/librostime.so
#7  0x00007ffff397714c in tf2_ros::Buffer::canTransform(std::string const&, std::string const&, ros::Time const&, ros::Duration, std::string*) const ()
   from /opt/ros/hydro/lib/libtf2_ros.so
#8  0x00007ffff4ae6aea in tf::Transformer::waitForTransform(std::string const&, std::string const&, ros::Time const&, ros::Duration const&, ros::Duration const&, std::string*) const () from /opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tf/_tf.so
#9  0x00007ffff4adac99 in ?? () from /opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tf/_tf.so
#10 0x0000000000466254 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx ()
#11 0x000000000057bd02 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx ()
#12 0x000000000057c77d in PyRun_FileExFlags ()
#13 0x000000000057e4a1 in PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags ()
#14 0x0000000000512cfd in Py_Main ()
#15 0x00007ffff68cc76d in __libc_start_main () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#16 0x000000000041ba51 in _start ()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/74278/cannot-use-ros::time::now()-before-the-first-nodehandle-has-been-created-or-ros::start()-has-been-called./) by [liborw](https://answers.ros.org/users/2302/liborw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 801 on 2013-08-22

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-08-22**:
This looks like something doesn't fit: The error looks like it's from a c++ binary.

**Comment by [liborw](https://answers.ros.org/users/2302/liborw/) on 2013-08-22**:
@dornhege, You are right, the problem is in the tf2 C++ library. I have added the backtrace.

**Comment by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on 2013-11-02**:
Any news about this? I've run into the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is being tracked as a ticket [here](https://github.com/ros/geometry/issues/30)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2013-12-18**:
Is this in the debs yet? I'm getting the same problem using ros-hydro-tf 1.10.6-0precise-20131107-0817-+0000

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-12-18**:
Do you have the newer version of tf2? That's where the fix is.  It looks like 0.4.8 or higher from the ticket.

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2013-12-18**:
I can make sure to update that, but explain why I should since I'm not using tf2?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-12-18**:
But you are, tf has no content anymore it calls tf2 for all methods.